# iOS 13 Background kill

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do you solve this problem : IOS 13 kept killing app instance after app entering background.

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication performSelector:@selector(sharedApplication)];
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
    // stopped or ending the task outright.
    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];

// Start the long-running task and return immediately.
[self deleteOldFilesWithCompletionBlock:^{
    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that it's because you are trying to call bgTask

```
[application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
```

and change it

```
bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
```

inside its definition.

Try to separate it for 2 different operations - bgTask definition and bgTask calling and changing.